# Warning "Fields .... is never assigned to and will always have its default value null"

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I am trying to insert the data into the database but the values inserted in the database are displayed null. There are also warnings like "Fields (x) is never assigned to and will always have its default value null"   ( x = response1, response2,  response3, response4, response5)

```
private void YesOrNoChecked(RadioButton radioButtonYes, RadioButton radioButtonNo,string response,int questionNo)
        {
            if (radioButtonYes.Checked)
            {
                response = "Yes";
            }
            else if (radioButtonNo.Checked)
            {
                response = "No";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Question " + questionNo + " is not answered", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                isChecked = false;
            }
        }

private void SatisfactionChecked(RadioButton rdoVerySatisfied, RadioButton rdoSatisfied, RadioButton rdoNeutral, 
            RadioButton rdoDissatisfied, RadioButton rdoVeryDissatisfied,string response,int questionNo)
        {
            if (rdoVerySatisfied.Checked)
            {
                response = "Very Satisfied";
            }
            else if (rdoSatisfied.Checked)
            {
                response = "Satisfied";
            }
            else if (rdoNeutral.Checked)
            {
                response = "Neutral";
            }
            else if (rdoDissatisfied.Checked)
            {
                response = "Dissatisfied";
            }
            else if (rdoVeryDissatisfied.Checked)
            {
                response = "Very Dissatisfied";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Question " + questionNo + " is not answered", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                isChecked = false;
            }
        }
```

I called the functions...

```
    YesOrNoChecked(rdoYes1, rdoNo1, response1, 1); 
    YesOrNoChecked(rdoYes2, rdoNo2, response2, 2);  
    SatisfactionChecked(rdoVerySatisfied3, rdoSatisfied3, rdoNeutral3, rdoDissatisfied3, rdoVeryDissatisfied3, response3, 3);
    SatisfactionChecked(rdoVerySatisfied4, rdoSatisfied4, rdoNeutral4, rdoDissatisfied4, rdoVeryDissatisfied4, response4, 4);  
    SatisfactionChecked(rdoVerySatisfied5, rdoSatisfied5, rdoNeutral5, rdoDissatisfied5, rdoVeryDissatisfied5, response5, 5);
```

I insert the data into the database

```
consumerResponsesTableAdapter.InsertConsumerResponses(lblSurveyDate.Text,
                        consumerID, ConsumerMenu.surveyID, response1, response2, response3, response4, response5, response6);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the misunderstanding that if you assign a value to a C# method parameter, that the value will affect the variable passed as that parameter by the calling method. In pass-by-value semantics this is not the case.

You wrote:

```
    private void YesOrNoChecked(RadioButton radioButtonYes, RadioButton radioButtonNo,string response, ...)
    {
        if (radioButtonYes.Checked)
        {
            response = "Yes";
        }
```

You might call it like:

```
string x = "x";
YesOrNoChecked(rb1, rb2, x, ...);
```

But `x` will never, ever have "Yes" or "No" in it, it will always only ever have "x" in it.

The reason for this is because, even though `x` and `response` start out referring to the same thing when you call the method (they both refer to "x") your assigning `response = "Yes"` makes a new thing ("Yes") leaving x pointing to the old thing ("x"), then when the method finishes, `response` is deleted, so the "Yes" is lost, and `x` always only ever pointed to "x"

```
In steps:
x --> "x"                               Before you call the method
x --> "x" <-- response                  As soon as you call the method
x --> "x"     response --> "Yes"        During the method
x --> "x"     response --> (is lost)    After the method finishes
```

---

To get it to work like that, you could use `out` modifier but I wouldn't recommend it (there are nearly never any reasons to use `out` parameters in C#). Instead, modify your methods to `return` the "Yes" or "No" and capture it when you call the method:

```
    private string YesOrNoChecked(RadioButton radioButtonYes, RadioButton radioButtonNo)
    {
        if (radioButtonYes.Checked)
        {
            return "Yes";
        }
```

and use it like:

```
string x = YesOrNoChecked(rb1,rb2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have improved the code and this actually helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword out in input parameters for response string

```
private void YesOrNoChecked(RadioButton radioButtonYes, RadioButton radioButtonNo,
 out string response,int questionNo)
        {

             response=null;
            ..... your code
}
  
          
private void SatisfactionChecked(RadioButton rdoVerySatisfied, RadioButton rdoSatisfied, RadioButton rdoNeutral,  RadioButton rdoDissatisfied, RadioButton rdoVeryDissatisfied, 
out string response,int questionNo)
{
            response=null;
            ..... your code
{

//use it like this:
YesOrNoChecked(..., out response1, ...);
SatisfactionChecked(.., out response3, ...);
```

or you can check a return from void to string and remove response from input parameters:

```
private string YesOrNoChecked(RadioButton radioButtonYes, RadioButton radioButtonNo,int questionNo)
        {
  string  response=null;

            ..... your code

        return response;
}
  
          
private string SatisfactionChecked(RadioButton rdoVerySatisfied, RadioButton rdoSatisfied, RadioButton rdoNeutral, 
            RadioButton rdoDissatisfied, RadioButton rdoVeryDissatisfied, int questionNo)
{
         string  response=null;

            ..... your code

        return response;
{

//use it like this:
var response1=YesOrNoChecked(...);
var response3=SatisfactionChecked(...);
```